# Simple regular expression replacing colons

Tags: php, regex

I need  a simple regexp for php preg_replace:

Input: Quick brown :no: fox etc
Output: Quick brown !|no|! fox etc

:something: 
to 
!|something|!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = preg_replace('/:([^ ]+):/', '!|$1|!', $input);
```

You might want to replace `[^ ]` with a more specific set, depending on what you are expecting to be in between the `:`s.

Comment: if you want more than one word between the colons to be replaced like that, use Gumbo's code (or replace `[^ ]` with `[^:]`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/:([^:]+):/', '!|\\1|!', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on if a space is allowed between the colons. If it isn't:

```
$out = preg_replace('!:([^ ]+):!', '!|$1|!', $in);
```

is fine. You may also want to consider using a non-greedy expression instead:

```
$out = preg_replace('!:(.+?):!', '!|$1|!', $in);
```

Here is another option:

```
$out = preg_replace('!:([^:]+):!', '!|$1|!', $in);
```